# Calling Jquery function in Angular - My question is different

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, twitter-bootstrap-3

As i'm running out of different project structure and other NPM issue, i'm not able to install/update my NPM. so not able install **ngbootstrap**

My actual issue is, im trying to using bootstrap carousal autoplay . for that i tried default attributes

```
data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000"
```

no changes happened.

and then tried below style directly in my component css file. that's also **NOT** working.

```
.carousel-inner > item {
    /*position: relative;
    display: none;*/
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out left;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out left;
    -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out left;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out left;
}
```

finally, i got it  working when using as usual jquery method and its gave me expected result.

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 5000
        });
```

But as per Angular rule, its not at all good practice to use jquery in Angular app.

Could someone suggest me effective way to achieve this carousal auto-play. Or please help me to convert Jquery method into equivalent Angular/ Typescript snippet. I'm seeking for help not code for me concept :)

Comment: you should be using ng-bootstrap carousel  instead of using jquery  https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples

Comment: @JoelJoseph sorry i update my content. im not using ngbootstrap